# Tile packaging geometry error?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector-tiles

Following the Arcmap 10.6.1 help content instructions, I'm attempting to create a tile package on my local drive, using File > Share As > Tile Package...

However, I get this error:

[image]

I find “invalid geometry” odd, because all of the data in the TOC (seven vector layers) is SDE – and all SDE vector data supposedly has its geometry checked upon ingestion by default.  But just in case, I ran the Check Geometry tool on all my layers, and as expected, there were no errors returned.

All layers are in the same CRS.

Customize > ArcMap Options > Sharing > Enable ArcGIS Runtime Tools is checked on.

The Geoprocessing Results window is empty, so I can’t examine the error further.

When I do an internet search on the phrase *The junction has invalid geometry*, nothing matching is returned.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

File > Share As > Tile Package did not work, even though it was described in the help contents as the method to use.

What **did** work was the **Create Map Tile Package** tool; no errors, no hiccups, and the output worked just fine.